is it conventional for the induced current in a DC machine to flow in the direction of increasing induced electromotive force (emf)?
I'm learning about DC machines and in one of the figures, I noticed that the induced current flows in the direction of increasing ind. emf.
When I think about the two concepts (induced current and induced emf) separately this does make sense because at the instant the loop starts rotating ccw the magnetic flux that goes through the loop will change, so current will be induced as shown in the figure to counteract that change. Also, the motional emf due to the Lorentz force formula explains the direction of the induced emf.
Is it conventional for the induced current to flow in the direction of increasing induced voltage (from negative to positive terminal)?

Electric Machinery Fundamentals 5th Edition, Stephen J. Chapman, McGraw-Hill (p. 406)

Electric Machinery Fundamentals 5th Edition, Stephen J. Chapman, McGraw-Hill (p. 406)
